# Python UDP socket, unknown delay

Tags: python, sockets, udp, real-time, delay

I am sending 32bytes data from a real-time application to a python instance using UDP sockets every 1ms. The sender is configured to send 1ms temporal resolution UDP packets. In the receiving end, after every few iterations, I am having a delay of 15 or 16 ms. Could anyone please help me in understanding why?
Using a windows Virtual machine. Intel Xeon Gold 5120 2 core CPU, 2.20 GHz, 6 GB RAM, with Windows 10 Pro OS.

```
## Import necessary libraries

import socket
import time
"""
just get the raw values from UDP socket every 1ms
The sender sends it with that temporal resolution

"""

UDP_IP = "10.10.114.22"
UDP_PORT = 8208 #UDP phasor values 32 bytes (V,phi,P)
sock_ph = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
sock_ph.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print("socket bound, waiting for data...")

while True:
    time_before_raw = time.monotonic_ns()
    raw = sock_ph.recv(32) #I am receiving 32 bytes data
    time_after_raw = time.monotonic_ns()
    print((time_after_raw-time_before_raw),raw,len(raw))
```

The printed output is as follows:

[image: Output showing unknown delay]

I tried with wireshark and could see the data packets coming at 1ms gap. So basically the python socket is probably having some buffering issue.
[image: Wireshark screenshot, showing 1ms temporal resolution of data]

Upon further investigation it is seen that 14-16 UDP packets are coming in the python environment almost all at once (0 ms delay between them), then after 14-16ms the next batch of packets are coming. It is as if there is some sort of a buffer.

Comment: Given that the only times you show are 0 and 16ms, I suspect your clock just ticks in 16ms increments.

Comment: What happens if you use `time.perf_counter_ns()`?

Comment: The same, there is a genuine case of holding 14-16 data packets and then sending them at once. It is not a timing issue, but some sort of data buffer issue. At least i think so. I tried datetime, time.perft...but the result is always the same. 14-16 packets at the same timestamp and thean 14-16ms delay and then the next 14-16 packets.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you use `socket.TCP_NODELAY`? It's probably irrelevant but I've got no clue. `recvmsg_into` is also something I would try (which avoids the Python buffer). I do however feel it has to do more with the OS than Python. Please add OS name and version.

Comment: Using a windows Virtual machine. Intel Xeon Gold 5120 2 core CPU, 2.20 GHz, 6 GB RAM, with Windows 10 Pro OS.

Comment: You've intrigued me. Maybe it has to do with scheduling? Try setting the process priority to realtime. You can do that using task manager, then right click on process, and set priority to realtime.

Comment: @Bharel TCP_NODELAY is specific to TCP sockets (as suggested by the name); UDP sockets don't use Nagle's algorithm in any case, so trying to disable Nagle's algorithm on a UDP socket won't help anything.

Comment: Note that printing output to stdout can sometimes be a slow operation.  You'll get more accurate timing measurements if you don't print out anything during the time-sensitive portions of the test, but rather just append the timing values into a list (or whatever) and then print them out only at the end of the program.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I tried this as you suggested. The same result. The delay is in the recv not the print.

Comment: @Rambopartyush try temporarily commenting out your `recv()` call and run the loop with only the calls to `time.monotonic_ns()` collecting timestamps for a few seconds -- then look at the results and see how the clock values are behaving, in particular whether they are increasing smoothly or "jumping" by multiple milliseconds at intervals.   If it's the latter, then part of the problem is that your clock isn't fine-grained enough to capture the resolution you want to capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is due to the temporal resolution of `monotonic_ns()`, `time.perf_counter_ns()` solved this issue.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/#id23

Comment: 16ms delays remind of 60 frame per s cap in windows;
there is a python library `psychopy` which has timers and countdown clocks of different temporal resolution; check it out to find out how to implement the one which doesnt depend on OS caps